# How do I find the number of inversions in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compare, inversion

Basically I'm trying to write an algorithm in Java to determine the number of pairs in an array that are out of order. So if we take i and j and j is in a higher position in an array than i but A[i] > A[j] then it counts those two numbers as an inversion. Currently this is what I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++){
    if (A[i] > A[i+1]){
        k++;
```

What this does is only compared the pairs that are right next to eachother so now I'm trying to modify this to find any two numbers in the array where the lower position is a higher value than the number in the higher position. I know how to do something like that but I want the run time to be (n+k) where n is the length of the array and k is the number of inversions in the array.

EDIT: Here's my attempt to implement insertion sort:

```
int k = 0;
int [] A = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
int n = A.length;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    int temp = A[i];
    int j;
    for (j = i - 1; j >=0 && temp < A[j]; j--){
        A[j + 1] = A[j];
    A[j + 1] = A[j];
        k++;
```

k is supposed to be keep track of how many inversions. For the array 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 the number I get returned is 6. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to implement insertion sort, and count the number of times that a pair of adjacent elements were swapped. This works because insertion sort performs a swap for and only for each inversion. In fact its running time is *O*(*n* + *k*), just as you requested.

---

As for question part two - here is the corrected insertion sort algorithm:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    int temp = A[i];
    int j;
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp < A[j]; j--) {
        A[j + 1] = A[j];
        k++;  // Number of inversions
    }
    A[j + 1] = temp;
}
```

---

Extra note: The efficient way to count array inversions is to modify the merge sort algorithm, which runs in *O*(*n* log *n*) time. However when *k* is small, *O*(*n* + *k*) is approximately *O*(*n*), which is less than *O*(*n* log *n*). Indeed, merge sort's best-case time is still *O*(*n* log *n*), whereas insertion sort's best case is *O*(*n*). Therefore, merge sort *does not* answer the OP's question for an *O*(*n* + *k*) algorithm.

Comment: So are inversions only for pairs next to eachother or is it for any pair?

Comment: is my answer is correct or i misunderstood question?

Comment: @JoshSusa: Insertion sort counts inversions for each pair. The reasoning is a bit complicated because insertion sort modifies the array as it goes.

Comment: @Lakhan: Your algorithm produces the right count, but markspace pointed out that it runs too slowly, in O(n^2) time.

Comment: is it helpful or not?

Comment: So I tried to implement insertion sort (see the updated code above) but it keeps giving me an out of bounds exception. Why is that?

Comment: Now it returns 10 for the number of inversions. I assume that the runtime is O(n + k) due it it being insertion sort.

Comment: The answer should be 10. I double-checked my algorithm and it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Inversion Count for an array indicates – how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If array is already sorted then inversion count is 0. If array is sorted in reverse order that inversion count is the maximum. 
Formally speaking, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j Example:
The sequence 2, 4, 1, 3, 5 has three inversions (2, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3).

For each element, count number of elements which are on right side of it and are smaller than it.

```
int getInvCount(int arr[], int n)
{
  int inv_count = 0;
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)
      if(arr[i] > arr[j])
        inv_count++;

  return inv_count;
}

/* Driver progra to test above functions */
int main(int argv, char** args)
{
  int arr[] = {1, 20, 6, 4, 5};
  printf(" Number of inversions are %d \n", getInvCount(arr, 5));
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not, however, O(n+k) running time as the OP requested, but O(n^2).  I don't see any other way to implement this however.  The OP may just be out of luck.